# Beautiful soup unable to find data from website with Div

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Im trying to **scrape** data from a website but nothing is being returned.

I've tried to extract it in multiple ways but the data held within div id ="app" never shows up.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://westgate-production-4cb87.firebaseapp.com/super-contests/weekly-card/embed')
res = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

When I print soup it just shows div id ="app" but not the contents within the div. I've also tried to find tables, table rows etc within soup but it always returns a blank dataset.

I know there are a number of similar questions to this but none seem to cover a situation where none of the data is showing up.

Appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application is taking time to load the page fully.Provide some sleep() to load the page and then take driver.page_source to get the entire html content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://westgate-production-4cb87.firebaseapp.com/super-contests/weekly-card/embed')
time.sleep(5)
res=driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "lxml")
print(soup)
```